# Override ExecuteResult method and set Content-Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I've inherited a class from ActionResult and then overrided the ExecuteResult method.

```
public class CustomResult : ActionResult
{
    public object Result { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; private set; }

    public CustomResult(int statusCode, object Result)
    {
        this.Result = Result;
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
        if (StatusDescription != null)
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = StatusDescription;

        HttpResponseBase Response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
    }
}
```

When I return a CustomResult object from the controller, the returned Content-Type to the view is always "text/html" and not "application/json" as setted on CustomResult class.

If I run this application locally all works fine, but when I deploy this one to the Azure App Service the Content-Type is always text/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! I've added this line `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` to the Response object.

Comment: Hmmm this sounds like a hack. I'd guess there's something going wrong in your web pipeline that causes the response to be the IIS web error page which is "text/html".

Comment: I've done some tests and this issue only happen in case of HTTP 500 status code. I haven't found any documentation about the Azure WebApp IIS pipeline, so I suppose for HTTP 500 status code Azure have a default behavior that modify the response to text/html Content-Type. In the Azure portal I haven't found any property to modify this behavior. This is also the reason for that in local debug all work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, it could work correctly in the Azure Web App. It works correctly for me even I published the WebApp to Azure environment. If it is possible, please have a try to check it with Fiddler tool.

[image]

Comment: I've captured with Fiddler traffic from local instance and from the Azure Web App so, starting the same request, I've in response application/json in local and text/html in Azure. I'm going crazy...

Comment: please have a try to deploy a new WebApp. And Check whether there is something set in the webconfig or Appsettings

Comment: I've deployed to a new WebApp but there is the same issue. In the application properties on Azure or in the web.config there are no settings that might suggest a different behavior of the content-type.